# window.event value is same as function param "e"

Tags: javascript, browser, event-listener

Can anyone explain the reason for this? Given that window.event is not defined anywhere and after this callback if you check window.event, it comes as *undefined*.
I have checked this on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, the behavior is the same.
This is also applicable for **onmessage**.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        console.log("event clicked: ", e); // PointerEvent
        console.log(window.event); // PointerEvent
    })
```

NOTE: Once you set window.event , then it doesn't behave like this.

Reason for this behaviour of the browsers

Comment: Because that's how it was implemented

Comment: why it is implemented in this way, any idea? and it behaves in this way only because of historical reasons?

Comment: Yes, since it's now deprecated - means it was left from some time ago for one reason or another

Answer (score 0):

[`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) is deprecated and should not be used.

It is left over from the very early days of JavaScript on the WWW when event handlers were attached using `onclick` and similar intrinsic event attributes instead of `addEventListener`.